Can I have multiple SSIDs with the same name?
This is a basic question about how SSIDs work.
If I have two wifi LANs separated so there's no signal overlap, and I give both hotspots the same SSID name but a different password, will that cause a problem moving a client from one hotspot to the other back and forth?
In other words, is there a number (analogous to an IP address underneath the domain name with TCPIP) associated with that name that's different on the two networks so that the client will know they are different networks and will knows to connect automatically with the correct respective password?
You might ask why not make the password the same or have the SSIDs be different and I'd do that, but the admin is being resistant to doing that for some reason.

It matters not if the passwords are the same because the networks will be different, and a user could not seamlessly roam.

I've never seen a wifi system that will allow one to create multiple "profiles" using the same SSID, so there's no way you'd be able to seamlessly use both. You'd have to manually connect to each, changing the password each time. Systems also tend to think an SSID defines a network, so the same SSID on different networks tend to confuse things. (i.e. DHCP won't restart but will continue with the wrong network config.)


give both hotspots the same SSID name but a different password,

That's gonna be a problem, as a client cannot distinguish between both networks and there's no reasonable way to store two passwords for the same SSID - the user would have to enter the correct one, depending on location.
The SSID is the service set identifier that designates the network. There's no other, hidden ID for it.

BSSID - the MAC of the AP. So there is a way to ID the exact system, but no one actually tracks the BSSID. 'tho I've seen systems that can blacklist BSSID's for any specific SSID.

That's what I thought: "The SSID is the service set identifier that designates the network. There's no other, hidden ID for it." but it appears to work today. Both SSID names are identical, and I attached to each one with their respective passwords, and I've been able to go back and forth without having to give the password and I was wondering why that was working (tho I'm not complaining :-)
